# Rename iphone4 to iphone-4

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonyms

To be consistent with [iphone-3g](/questions/tagged/iphone-3g), [iphone-3gs](/questions/tagged/iphone-3gs), and our general rules for converting spaces to hyphens, pls to rename [iphone4](/questions/tagged/iphone4) to [iphone-4](/questions/tagged/iphone-4).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Done. That was *way* overdue. Thanks!

Comment: Impressive speed, Herr Unicron.